# Formatting output from playlist-only download from youtube-dl

Tags: windows, text-formatting, youtube-dl, playlists, jq

In reference to question [youtube-dl; How download ONLY the playlist, NOT the files therein](https://superuser.com/questions/1341684/youtube-dl-how-download-only-the-playlist-not-the-files-therein)

Can i get output like the following :

```
https://youtu.be/0gvUCLL-UGE | video title
https://youtu.be/CPV7zcUy4J0 | video title
https://youtu.be/4wyZNwIrH9I | video title
```

Example :

```
https://youtu.be/aYLBLOQrcAE | 5 More Amazing Kitchen Gadgets
```

The solution provided by @radiolondra works great,

```
youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist "https://" | jq -r '.id' | sed 's_^_https://youtu.be/_' > result.log
```

But, I am not able to figure out "JQ" command / query for my requirement.

Please Assist!

------------------Edited------------------

I tried jq -r ".id \ "+" .title"
the output was

```
https://youtu.be/0gvUCLL-UGEvideo title
```

was not able to insert " | " in between [id] and [title] Others that ended with error:

```
jq -r "map([.id, .title] | join("| ")) | join('\n')"
jq -r "map([.id, .title] | join(", ")) | join('\n')"
jq -r "map([.id, .title] | join(', ')) | join('\n')"
jq -r "map([.id, .title] | join('| ')) | join('\n')"
jq -r "map([.id, .title] | join(" ")) | join('\n')"
jq -r "map([.id, .title] | join(' ')) | join('\n')"
```

-----------------------Edited-----------------------

Following modifications seems to be working in Linux, but not able to make them work on windows :

```
 
jq -r '.entries | map(.id +" | "+ .title) | join("\n")'
jq -r '.[] | map(.id +" | "+ .title) | join("\n")'
```

On windows i keep getting the following error:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
'.entries
jq: 1 compile error
'map' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What adjustments have you tried in the script? Have you looked up jq and sed to figure out what they are doing and how they might be used to get what you want?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

This filter works for me:

```
jq -r '[("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + .url), .title] | join(" | ")'
```

For example:

```
$ youtube-dl -j --flat-playlist "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_-YkHMlMW8l2yE_vwl8Wg1U1k5kPHq_7" | jq -r '[("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + .url), .title] | join(" | ")'
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWYlIaYIcuI | Joshua Lee Turner - Introduction (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8F4Pjv3NXQ | Joshua Lee Turner - Nebraska Dreams (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgXtIA7o-jY | Joshua Lee Turner - Like Lightning (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bl9Ium3ZLCU | Joshua Lee Turner - Belle (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZSzqL-asiY | Joshua Lee Turner - 319 (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGLs5nPKJio | Joshua Lee Turner - Public Life (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUbqL_Yhekk | Joshua Lee Turner - Smoky Sunrise (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KLMZ-k3UxU | Joshua Lee Turner - Nostalgia / So Far So Long (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFtN8FPUWDQ | Joshua Lee Turner - Denouement (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmiOm0XeV00 | Joshua Lee Turner - At Home (Official)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Fs18SpOmRM | Joshua Lee Turner - Public Life Full Album (Official)
```